# Can I use equality operators within switch statements?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use operators like `!=` and `==` within a `switch` statement, but with all of the testing I've done I can't find a way to do it without using `if` statements.

I've tried putting the operator before and after the `case` with a value.

This is what I've tried:

```cpp
int main(){
    int value = 12;
    switch(value){
        case != 12:
            cout << "Inequal \n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "The value is 12 \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: please share the code

Comment: If you can't find a way without using an `if` statement, why don't you use an `if` statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to compare a variable of some kind using an equality operator in a `case` label. You can only put a constant expression between the `case` keyword and the `:`. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

> attr(optional) `case constant_expression : statement`

Further more the constrains below apply:

> constant_expression   -   a constant expression of the same type as the type of condition after conversions and integral promotions

Since the result of an equality operator is boolean, then even if it was constant expression it would require that the type within the `switch` part was boolean as well. You cannot use the equality operators for this, unless they are used as constant expressions, and the type of the switch is boolean.

Comment: After some testing I assumed you couldn't do this, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

No. The case statements within a switch statement need to be compile time constants. If you need to switch based on a runtime result, you need to use if/else.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use operators in `case` statements, only constants, which are compared as-is to the `switch` condition.

But, for the specific example to have shown, you can tweak the code a little to accomplish the result you are looking for:

```cpp
int main(){
    int value = 12;
    switch(value){
        case 12:
            cout << "The value is 12 \n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Inequal \n";
    }
}
```

But this is no better than a simpler `if/else`:

```cpp
int main(){
    int value = 12;
    if (value == 12) {
        cout << "The value is 12 \n";
    } else {
        cout << "Inequal \n";
    }
}
```

```cpp
int main(){
    int value = 12;
    if (value != 12) {
        cout << "Inequal \n";
    } else {
        cout << "The value is 12 \n";
    }
}
```